# How can I create new data frame columns corresponding to levels of a given column using the plyr package in R?

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I am looking for an "elegant" way to basically split a data frame by the levels of one column variable, then create a new output data frame reshaped to now drop the factor variable and add new columns for the levels of the factor variable. I can do this with functions such as the split() method, but this seems to be the messy way to me. I have been trying to do this using the melt() and cast() functions in the plyr package, but haven't been successful in getting the exact output I need.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
> jumbo.df = read.csv(...)
> head(jumbo.df)
         PricingDate  Name     Rate 
    186  2012-03-05   Type A   2.875  
    187  2012-03-05   Type B   3.250  
    188  2012-03-05   Type C   3.750  
    189  2012-03-05   Type D   3.750  
    190  2012-03-05   Type E   4.500  
    191  2012-03-06   Type A   2.875
```

What I would like to do is split by the variable *name*, remove *Name* and *Rate*, then output columns for *Type A*, *Type B*, *Type C*, *Type D*, and *Type E* with the corresponding Rate series with Date as ID:

```
> head(output.df)
         PricingDate  Type A   Type B    Type C    Type D    Type E 
         2012-03-05    2.875    3.250     3.750     3.750     4.500  
         2012-03-06    2.875    ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your example makes no sense. If you split by `Name`, then how on earth do you get all names for each date in the output? If you split by `Name`, then all `Type A` will be one object and so on. Perhaps you mean split by `PricingDate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I get you right, but could it be that you just want to reshape your data into the wide format? If so, you have to use the `melt` and `cast` functions of the `reshape` (!) package. `reshape2` is basically the same. Since your data is already in the molten format, i.e. the long format, a one-liner does what you want:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("PricingDate  Name     Rate 
                                 2012-03-05   TypeA   2.875  
                                 2012-03-05   TypeB   3.250  
                                 2012-03-05   TypeC   3.750  
                                 2012-03-05   TypeD   3.750  
                                 2012-03-05   TypeE   4.500  
                                 2012-03-06   TypeA   2.875"), header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, PricingDate ~ Name)
Using Rate as value column: use value.var to override.
  PricingDate TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeD TypeE
1  2012-03-05 2.875  3.25  3.75  3.75   4.5
2  2012-03-06 2.875    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

    data <- structure(list(PricingDate = c("2012-03-05", "2012-03-05", "2012-03-05", 
    "2012-03-05", "2012-03-05", "2012-03-06", "2012-03-06", "2012-03-06", 
    "2012-03-06", "2012-03-06"), Name = c("Type A", "Type B", "Type C", 
    "Type D", "Type E", "Type A", "Type B", "Type C", "Type D", "Type E"
    ), Rate = c(2.875, 3.25, 3.75, 3.75, 4.5, 4.875, 5.25, 6.75, 
    7.75, 8.5)), .Names = c("PricingDate", "Name", "Rate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("186", 
    "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195"
    ))


    > data
        PricingDate   Name  Rate
    186  2012-03-05 Type A 2.875
    187  2012-03-05 Type B 3.250
    188  2012-03-05 Type C 3.750
    189  2012-03-05 Type D 3.750
    190  2012-03-05 Type E 4.500
    191  2012-03-06 Type A 4.875
    192  2012-03-06 Type B 5.250
    193  2012-03-06 Type C 6.750
    194  2012-03-06 Type D 7.750
    195  2012-03-06 Type E 8.500


    ddply(data, .(PricingDate), function(x) reshape(x, idvar="PricingDate", timevar="Name", direction="wide"))



    PricingDate Rate.Type A Rate.Type B Rate.Type C Rate.Type D
    1  2012-03-05       2.875        3.25        3.75        3.75
    2  2012-03-06       4.875        5.25        6.75        7.75
      Rate.Type E
    1         4.5
    2         8.5
```